# Keep password abstracted when running CLI on production

Tags: linux, bash, security, percona

I would like to be able to use a command-line tool ([`pt-online-schema-change`](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-online-schema-change.html)) on my production server. There are two options regarding entering the database password, you can enter it directly in the command i.e.

```sh
pt-online-schema-change --alter "ADD COLUMN c1 INT" D=sakila,t=actor,u=root --pasword=securepassword
```

The other option is to do

```sh
pt-online-schema-change --alter "ADD COLUMN c1 INT" D=sakila,t=actor,u=root --ask-pass
```

which will prompt the user to enter the password. In both of these cases a user needs to have access to the production database password. Is there any reasonable way to abstract the password away or is there a different approach that might make more sense?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any reasonable way to abstract the password away or is there a different approach that might make more sense?

Yes: Kerberos.

MySQL supports Kerberos.  You want to check for Kerberos support in Percona (I've never used it.)  If it supports it, then "all" you have to do is set up Kerberos.

More generally, you want a way to pass your logged-in credentials to the DBMS back-end.  Sending a password in the clear over the network is what gave telnet(1) and ftp(1) a bad name.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to interact with the program without having to type the password, you could first prompt for the password as a shell variable, like this:

```
read -rs PASSWORD
export PASSWORD
```

then later run the command that uses the saved variable:

```
pt-online-schema-change ...  --pasword=${PASSWORD}
```

Comment: You might as well put the password in ~/.netrc then.  Anyone with sufficient privilege can read that file or a process's environment.

Comment: And the cleartext password will still be visible in `ps` output.

Comment: Both points are valid, but it's also valid that OP didn't specify any constraints about where the password should or should not be read.